# DNS Simple serving heroku http endpoint

Tags: heroku, dns, ssl-certificate

I am attempting to secure my website with https and have hit a weird issue.

When I go to my site I am getting the message:

"You attempted to reach www.site.com but you actually reached a server identifying itself as *.herokuapp.com"

I did some research and ran dig. I realized that the DNS servers are still pointing to the http endpoint. What is confusing me as that isn't set anywhere and hasn't been for several hours. Everything in for my domain is pointing to my ssl endpoint. Has anyone else ran into this issue?

Here is check via curl if it it useful:

```
curl -kvI https://www.app.com                                                                                                                                                
* Adding handle: conn: 0x7fc90c004000
* Adding handle: send: 0
* Adding handle: recv: 0
* Curl_addHandleToPipeline: length: 1
* - Conn 0 (0x7fc90c004000) send_pipe: 1, recv_pipe: 0
* About to connect() to www.app.com port 443 (#0)
*   Trying 23.23.80.206...
* Connected to www.app.com (23.23.80.206) port 443 (#0)
* TLS 1.2 connection using TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256
* Server certificate: *.herokuapp.com
* Server certificate: DigiCert SHA2 High Assurance Server CA
* Server certificate: DigiCert High Assurance EV Root CA
> HEAD / HTTP/1.1
> User-Agent: curl/7.30.0
> Host: www.app.com
> Accept: */*
>
< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
* Server Cowboy is not blacklisted
< Server: Cowboy
Server: Cowboy
< Connection: keep-alive
Connection: keep-alive
< X-Powered-By: Express
X-Powered-By: Express
< Vary: Accept-Encoding
Vary: Accept-Encoding
< Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
< Content-Length: 6423
Content-Length: 6423
< Set-Cookie: keystone.sid=s%3ALPqdigZI_LkiadVQl_YJzfoB.pcwuRSrFuZ3kpUWC9W2z1%2FF60rTipweUf5gwedehJz4; Path=/; HttpOnly
Set-Cookie: keystone.sid=s%3ALPqdigZI_LkiadVQl_YJzfoB.pcwuRSrFuZ3kpUWC9W2z1%2FF60rTipweUf5gwedehJz4; Path=/; HttpOnly
< Date: Wed, 10 Sep 2014 02:46:55 GMT
Date: Wed, 10 Sep 2014 02:46:55 GMT
< Via: 1.1 vegur
Via: 1.1 vegur
```

Comment: Sorry for the very slow reply, haven't logged in to the site in a while. Anyway for me it was just a waiting game. I gave up on it and when I checked it the next morning everything worked.